# web.config secure directory with gal group

Tags: .net, security, active-directory, web-config

So, I have the following in the web.config

```
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>         
        <allow users="domain\johndoe" />

        <!--Deny All Others-->
        <deny users="*" /> 
    </authorization>
```

But, what I want to do, is only allow users in a specific GAL group on our AD server and that doesn't seem to work with these settings.

Is there an authentication mode that will?  Everything I find referencing AD wants to use forms!  Which I do not want.

Comment: What ASP.NET Membership Provider are you using?  Is it `System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`?  If not, that could be the start of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it a simply as settings within the Authorization tag.  Check out the Acitve Directory membership provider - perhaps that is what you want...

[How To: Use Forms Authentication with Active Directory in Multiple Domains in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998345.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="*" roles="domain/group" />
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: That's not even valid xml, it won't parse

Comment: Doesn't work, works for an NT group, but not a GAL group as defined in AD

Answer (score 0):

I think your group needs to be a security group, not a distribution group (at least, that is the problem I'm having right now)